# SQL table column values to select query list

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

So I have a table that has EMAIL and Order ID.

```
EMAIL   |   id
--------------
Y@a.com |   1
Y@a.com |   2
X@a.com |   3
```

And I need to `SELECT` it so that I'd have email column that is distinct and ids column that is array of int's

```
EMAIL   |   ids
--------------
Y@a.com |   [1,2]
X@a.com |   [3]
```

I use PSQL 9.3. I looked at aggregate functions, but since I'm not too good with SQL atm, I didn't really understand them. My code so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (email) email
FROM order
WHERE date > '2013-01-01';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the aggregate function [**`array_agg()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT email, array_agg(id) AS id_array
FROM   "order"
WHERE  date > '2013-01-01'
GROUP  BY email;
```

#### Aside: your identifiers ...

Don't use `order` as table name, it's a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).
Don't use `date` as column name, it's a reserved word in standard SQL and a basic type name in Postgres.
I wouldn't use `id` as column name either, that's a common anti-pattern, but "id" is not a descriptive name. Once you join a couple of tables you have n columns named "id" and you need to start dealing out column aliases, not to speak of the confusion it may cause.

Instead, use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE order_data (
   order_data_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , email         text
 , order_date    date
);
```

Comment: urr.. I was so sure that I tryed that `array_agg(id)`. And thanks for pointers in style. :)